# Replacing values in text file by transformation table in text file

Tags: r, text-files

I have the following text file (T1.txt):

```
"se" "su"
"1" "<{OV1}>" 0.0754101809002945
"2" "<{OV2},{OV4}>" 0.071729070256626
"3" "<{OV3},{OV5},{OV2},{OV4}>" 0.0703618005889777
"4" "<{OV1},{OV3},{OV4}>" 0.0704669751787968
```

In addition, I have the following transformation table that is in text file (TR.txt):

```
"items" "newitem"
"1" "BA31 U1" "OV1"
"2" "BECE D2" "OV2"
"3" "26D695 UPE" "OV3"
"4" "2BC5A DATA; BreE 124" "OV4"
"5" "659 INTS" "OV5"
```

I would like to get the following by replacing each value in the source table by its equivalent in the transformation text file:

```
"se" "su"
"1" "<{BA31 U1}>" 0.0754101809002945
"2" "<{BECE D2},{2BC5A DATA; BreE 124}>" 0.071729070256626
"3" "<{26D695 UPE},{659 INTS},{BECE D2},{2BC5A DATA; BreE 124}>" 0.0703618005889777
"4" "<{BA31 U1},{26D695 UPE},{2BC5A DATA; BreE 124}>" 0.0704669751787968
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sour <- read.table("Source.txt", head=T, as.is=T, row.names=1)
trans <- read.table("Transofrmation Table.txt", head=T, as.is=T, row.names=1)

dim(sour)
dim(trans)
sour[1, ]
trans[1, ]

trans.tab <- trans$items
names(trans.tab) <- trans$newitem

for (i in 1:nrow(sour)) {
  x1 <- unlist(strsplit(sour$sequence[i], split="\\{|\\}"))
  x1 <- x1[-c(1, length(x1))]
  x1 <- x1[x1!=","]
  x2 <- rep("{", length(x1))
  x3 <- rep("},", length(x1))
  y <- paste(x2, trans.tab[x1], x3, sep="", collapse="")
  y <- gsub(",$", "", y)
  y <- paste("<", y, ">", sep="")
  sour$sequence[i] <- y
}

write.table(sour, file="Source.new.txt", quote=F, sep="\t", row.names=F)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dat1 <- read.table("T1.txt", head=T, as.is=T)
dat2 <- read.table("TR.txt", head=T, as.is=T)

> dat1
                         se         su
1                   <{OV1}> 0.07541018
2             <{OV2},{OV4}> 0.07172907
3 <{OV3},{OV5},{OV2},{OV4}> 0.07036180
4       <{OV1},{OV3},{OV4}> 0.07046698

> dat2
                 items newitem
1              BA31 U1     OV1
2              BECE D2     OV2
3           26D695 UPE     OV3
4 2BC5A DATA; BreE 124     OV4
5             659 INTS     OV5

for (i in 1:nrow(dat2)) {
  dat1$se <- gsub(dat2$newitem[i], dat2$items[i], dat1$se)
}

> dat1
                                                          se         su
1                                                <{BA31 U1}> 0.07541018
2                         <{BECE D2},{2BC5A DATA; BreE 124}> 0.07172907
3 <{26D695 UPE},{659 INTS},{BECE D2},{2BC5A DATA; BreE 124}> 0.07036180
4            <{BA31 U1},{26D695 UPE},{2BC5A DATA; BreE 124}> 0.07046698
```

Comment: Can you show the line in T1.txt and the corresponding line in the transformation table that caused this problem? @Avi